# Natural Cubic Spline 3 points

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, spline

I am trying to do a natural cubic spline but I'm having trouble.

f(-.0247500)=-.5, f(.3349375)=-.25, f(1.101000)=0

I tried doing the matrix, Ax=b where, h0=h1=.25 an a0=-.0247500, a1=.3349375, a2=1.1010000 but my answers were wrong I believe. So I decided to try another way which was,

S0(-.5)=-.0247500=a0

S0(-.25)=.3349375=a0+1/4b0+1/16co+1/64do

S1(-.25)=.3349375=a1

S1(0)=a1+1/4b1+1/16c1+1/64di=1.1010000

S'0(-.25)=b0+1/2c0+3/16do=S'1(-.25)=b1

S"0(-.25)=2c0+3/2d0=S"1(-.25)=b1

S"0(-.5)=2c0=0

S"1(0)=2c1+6d1=0

I am not sure how to solve these systems of equations or what to do. I need to learn how to construct on of these by hand so can you help me? I thought I was getting close when I tried to do it with Ax=b , h0=h1=.25 but I not sure how I keep getting the  wrong answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE and thank you for your question! It is rather hard to digest at the moment, due to loss of subscripts and overall typesetting. This site supports MathJax for rendering maths in a TeX-like way. For some basic information about using it see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 1):

**Update** You wrote the data points backwards, so I will swap those and rework the problem.

For your problem, we are given:

- $f(-.5) = -.0247500, f(-.25) = .3349375, f(0) = 1.101000$, so, we have the three points:

$$(x,y) = (-.5,-.0247500), (-.25, .3349375), (0, 1.101000)$$

This gives use the values:

- $a_0 = -0.02475$
- $a_1 =  0.334938$
- $c_0 = 0$
- $b_0 =  1.03238$
- $d_0 = 6.502$
- $b_1 = 2.2515$
- $c_1 = 4.8765$
- $d_1 = -6.502$

From this data, we write out the two cubic polynomials:

$$1.30419 + 5.90888 x + 9.753 x^2 + 6.502 x^3 \\ 1.101 + 3.47063 x - 6.502 x^3$$

**Aside**: the Wiki [*Spline interpolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Example) example more or less works, but is very confusing when interpreting the results, so buyer beware!

Comment: Hmm, would you mind to include the resulting two cubic polynomials, which allow then to interpolate in the two given intervals? I've been lost also in the wikipedia trying to find this out...

Comment: Amzoti - do you ask *me*? If so: I've only read wikipedia and have tried to make the given derivations usable for me - I just don't see how I can now select some value *x* say in the first interval and calculate with the above coefficients a value for *y*.  At least I could manage to express the logic of the cubic spline in a matrix-representation and to solve the problem of finding coefficients for the cubic polynomials by matrix-inversion. But this is *very uncool* for big matrices/many points, so I'd like to understand the ansatz with the tridiagonal matrix too.

Comment: Amzoti - that was the OP in his "thank you"-answer...

Comment: that makes sense. For some reason though my book shows a different answer the book says b0=1.0323750, b1=2.2515000, c0=0,c1=4.876500 , d0=6.502,d1=-6.502.. the matrix used in the book say a11=1 , a12=0, a13=0, a21=h0, a22=2(h0+h1), a23=h1, a31=0, a32=h1, a33=2(h1+h2) K0=0,K1=3/H1(A2-A1)-3/H0(a1-a0), k2=0

Comment: @amWhy The grey text in the comment field says *Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".* It's no problem to do this in rare cases, but this should not become regular behavior.

Comment: Book is numerical analysis, ninth edition by richard burden

Comment: I've been looking at these numbers all day, those are the right data points, but i may have noticed an error today while reworking the problem. When i was using the AX=B matrix to do it , I got 16c1=4.8765 , then c1=78.0240..but the answer shows that c1=4.8766, either i did something wrong or the answer in the back of the book is wrong. The thing is though when you plug the answers in the back of book into the equation it works. For example, S0(-.25)=a0+(1/4)b0+(1/16)c0+(1/64)d0=.3349375, plug in the answers given and you get .334937, same for S1(0)=a1+(1/4)bi+(1/16)c1+(1/64)d1=1.1010000

Comment: I reworked the problem and have a result too. Do you have a result?

Comment: yea i tried using systems of equations and got d0=1.44, b0=1.3485, d1=-1.44, b1=2.4285, c1=2.16..but im not so confident in these answers.

Comment: I get: $-0.481347+0.753113 x-0.0338047 x^2-0.455282x^3$ and $-0.506486+0.978281 x-0.706073 x^2+0.213767 x^3$. What is the book answer showing for these two?

Comment: The answers in the book show that a0=-.02475000, a1=.33493750, b0=1.03237500, b1=2.2515000, c0=0, c1=4.87650000, d0=6.5020000, d1=-6.5020000 ....i think they are either using systems of equations or the digonallly dominant matrix , h0=h1=h2=.25 and a11=1, a12=0, a13=0, a21=h0,a22=2(h0+h1), a23=h1, a31=0,a32=h1, a33=2(h1+h2) and B= ..b0=0, b1=(3/h1)(a2-a1)-(3/h0)(a1-a0), b2=0 for ax=b...where x would be c0, c1, c2

Comment: OP exchanged $x$ for $y$ in the data ...

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: Thank you! Rats, I should have surmised that! Now, I get the book results!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Please see update. Regards

Comment: Maple confirms your computation perfectly !

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: Thank you! This was driving me nuts! :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: You are very welcome! Regards